# Being connected to databases but not reading information

Tags: php, database

I write a website and i import database from localhost to cpanel. 
now  it is connect to database but not reading information from database.
it is my code

```
function config(){
    $server="server";
    $user="infir";
    $password="pass";
    $db="infir";
    $connect=mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$db);
    mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
    mysqli_query($connect,"SET NAME 'utf8'");
    return $connect;
}
```

Comment: there is nothing to read in the requests you typed

Comment: How do you know it is not reading? Are you executing a select query? Please show us what you are doing and what error messages you are receiving.

Comment: <?php
include_once 'functions.php';
function user_login($data)
{
    $connect = config();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_tbl WHERE username='$data[username]'";
    $row = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row);
    if ($res['password'] == $data['password']) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $res['name'];
        header("location:dashbord.php");
    } else {
        header("location:index.php?login=error");
    }
}

Comment: Post code in the questions, and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

While you are setting it up, you might as well use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php. It's a lot better for various reasons including protection against SQL injection, but anyway, here's how you can set it up.

```
   $dsn = 'mysql:127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=infir';

   $pdo= new PDO($dsn, $user, $pasword, array(
       PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   ));
```

From the docs, here's an example statement with bound parameters:

```
$st = self::$db->prepare(
    "insert into vendors set
    first_name = :first_name,
    last_name = :last_name"
);
$st->execute(array(
    ':first_name' => $first,
    ':last_name' => $last
));
```

Comment: PDO isn't safe against SQL injections by default - and neither is MySQLi. But MySQLi offers prepared statements too. There's nothing wrong with using MySQLi over PDO if that's one prefer - its a matter of opinion mostly.

Comment: yeah Qirel, fair point, however if he hasn't even set up his connection yet I'm guessing he could use either! Up to himself I guess!

Comment: The question uses MySQLi to connect with, so I'm assuming that's what OP wants to roll with ;-) Then there's no reason to swap for PDO out of the blue.